# Alsa devices under Wine

Tags: audio, wine, opensuse, alsa, spotify

I'm running OpenSuse 11.2 and Wine 1.1.28.

Even if audio is perfectly working fine for me (Skype, Banshee, etc), when I try to configure audio for Wine (to use Spotify) I cannot hear anything from the audio test.

In the winecfg audio tab, ALSA is checked, but no devices are available.
I tried to run alsaconf (it needs root permissions) but it returns:

> No supported PnP or PCI card found No
>   legacy drivers available, either.

Any idea?